# Loop through array of differently structured JSON objects/arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I feel like this is mostly an issue with how I'm looping through the JSON, so am posting that first. This is a series of JSON responses from Promise.allSettled() posted below.

The problem I am having is with the second "status" object between content and anoObject1 as I'm looping through the JSON responses. I've shown some console.logs() below that are successful

Here is the series of JSON responses:

```
[
    {
        "status": "fulfilled",
        "value": {
            "content": {
                "object1": {
                    "kv": "Y",
                    "kv1": "1000",
                    "kv2": {
                        "okv": "A",
                        "okv1": "1"
                    },
                    "kw": "A"
                }
            },
            "retrievalDate": "2022-05-04T23:01:57.710+0000"
        }
    },
    {
        "status": "fulfilled",
        "value": {
            "content": [
                {
                    "anoObject1": {
                        "ano": "A",
                        "ano1": {
                            "ona": "B",
                            "ona1": 11
                        },
                        "measureValue": "1.92",
                        "measureValue2": "N"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "anoObject2": {
                        "ano": "B",
                        "ano1": {
                            "ona": "Y",
                            "ona1": 11
                        },
                        "measureValue": "1.92",
                        "measureValue2": "N"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "retrievalDate": "2022-05-04T23:01:57.707+0000"
        }
    }
]
```

Here are the async fetch calls:

```
export async function allCallouts(key, value){

    const BASE_URL = 'https://baseurl.com/service/'
    const API_KEY = 'apikey'
    const endpoint1 = 'https://url1.com/a/';
    const endpoint2 = 'https://url1.com/b/';
    

    try{
        const results = await Promise.allSettled(
            [
                fetch(endpoint1).then((response) => response.json()),
                fetch(endpoint2).then((response) => response.json()),
            ]
        )
        return results
    } catch (error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Here is the function I am calling the first function from

```
async handleFetchCallouts() {

    returnedResults;

    await allCallouts(key, value)
        .then(results => {

            this.returnedResults = results

        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('this is err: ' + err);
        })


    let arrayLength = this.returnedResults.length

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

        //I am able to console.log(this.returnedResults[i].value.content)
        //it returns the response and number I am expecting
        //but the structure of the JSON response (above) is tripping me up
        

        if (this.returnedResults[i].value.content['object1'] != null) {

            //I can console.log() this successfully
            console.log(this.returnedResults[i].value.content['object1'].kv)

        }

        if (this.returnedResults[i].value.content['anoObject1'] != null) {

            //having trouble getting to this object and looping through each

        }

    }

}
```

Thank you for any help! If you see other design flaws with my code or an easier way to do things, please suggest.

Comment: `this.returnedResults[i].value.content` --> in the first case, this is an `object`. And it has the key `object1` - so, it works. In the second one, it is an array. And the array does not have the key `anoObject1`. Try `this.returnedResults[i].value.content[0].anoObject1` and that should get you access to the 0-th element of `content` array's `anoObject1`. And `this.returnedResults[i].value.content[1].anoObject1` will access the next one (with `ano: "B"`.

Comment: I tried `console.log(this.returnedResults[i].value.content[0].anoObject1)` but am getting this error: 

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Comment: One must not do `console.log` without encapsulating it within an `if` condition. So, please try like this: `if (this.returnedResults[i].value.content?.[0]?.anoObject1) { console.log(this.returnedResults[i].value.content[0].anoObject1); };`. This will `console.log` only when `content` has an element at 0-index & that element has a prop `anoObject1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `recursive` function and dont use any hardcoded key. Iterate through the content and check if value is an array using `Array.isArray`. If so then handle it in a different function and so for if value is of type `object`

```js
const arrayLength = [{
    "status": "fulfilled",
    "value": {
      "content": {
        "object1": {
          "kv": "Y",
          "kv1": "1000",
          "kv2": {
            "okv": "A",
            "okv1": "1"
          },
          "kw": "A"
        }
      },
      "retrievalDate": "2022-05-04T23:01:57.710+0000"
    }
  },
  {
    "status": "fulfilled",
    "value": {
      "content": [{
          "anoObject1": {
            "ano": "A",
            "ano1": {
              "ona": "B",
              "ona1": 11
            },
            "measureValue": "1.92",
            "measureValue2": "N"
          }
        },
        {
          "anoObject1": {
            "ano": "B",
            "ano1": {
              "ona": "Y",
              "ona1": 11
            },
            "measureValue": "1.92",
            "measureValue2": "N"
          }
        }
      ],
      "retrievalDate": "2022-05-04T23:01:57.707+0000"
    }
  }
]
for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength.length; i++) {
  const content = arrayLength[i].value.content;
  // checking if value is of type array or object
  if (Array.isArray(content)) {
    handleContentArray(content)

  } else if (content && typeof(content) === 'object') {
    handleContentObject(content)
  }
}

function handleContentArray(contentArray) {
  // iterate the array
  contentArray.forEach(item => {
    // if the content of the array is an object then call the function which handles the object
    if (item && typeof item === 'object') {
      handleContentObject(item)
    }
  })
}

function handleContentObject(contentObject) {
  // iterate through the key
  for (let keys in contentObject) {
    // if the value of the key is an object then recursively call the same function
    if (contentObject && typeof(contentObject[keys]) === 'object') {
      return handleContentObject(contentObject[keys])
    } else {
      // log the key value pair
      console.log(`KEY:- ${keys}, VALUE: - ${contentObject[keys]}`)

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution I have tried so far, but it is working well for the most part, in way less code than I anticipated writing, thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the help brk! I've upvoted and marked as best answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to ascertain if an object is an `Array` and customize how you handle the object accordingly.

```js
// Same structure as in the question, but removed extraneous 
// fields and compacted for the sake of brevity.
const input = `[
    {"value":{"content":{"object1":{"kv":"Y"}}}},
    {"value":{"content":[
        {"anoObject1":{"ano":"A"}},
        {"anoObject1":{"ano":"B"}}
    ]}}]`;

const result = JSON.parse(input);
for (const r of result) {
  const content = r.value.content;
  if (Array.isArray(content)) {
    for (const c of content) {
      console.log(`anoObject1.ano = ${c.anoObject1.ano}`);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(`object1.kv = ${content.object1.kv}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your second if statement in the for loop, you would have to iterate through all items under `value.content`. Replace the second if statement with this for a plug and play:

```js
if (Array.isArray(this.returnedResults[i].value.content)) for (let i of this.returnedResults[i].value.content) {

}
```

Inside the new loop, `i` will be equivalent to

```json
                {
                    "anoObject1": {
                        "ano": "A",
                        "ano1": {
                            "ona": "B",
                            "ona1": 11
                        },
                        "measureValue": "1.92",
                        "measureValue2": "N"
                    }
                }
```

The reason for this is that the second if statement was attempting to find a property/key of an array instead of each object in the array of objects.

I would also recommend reading up on the following to make your coding easier/better:

- [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)
- [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)/[for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
- [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)/[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)